# difference between upper integral and lower integral of a bounded function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, functional-analysis, analysis

I want to show that

> Let $f: [a,b]\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function. Then
> $$\bar\int_a^b f-  \underline\int_a^b f =\inf\{({U(f,P)-L(f,P):P\in\mathcal{P}[a,b]}\}$$

I know that $$\bar\int_a^b f=\inf\{{U(f,P):P\in\mathcal{P}[a,b]}\}$$
and
$$\underline\int_a^b f=\sup\{{L(f,P):P\in\mathcal{P}[a,b]}\}$$

I guess they are where I should start, but I can't figure out what to do next.
Any suggestions please?

Comment: $-\sup A= \inf(-A)$